# Other approach for handling this TSQL text manipulation

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have this following data:

```
0297144600-4799               0297485500-5599
```

The 0297485500-5599 based on observation always on position 31 char from the left which this is an easy approach.

But I would like to do is to anticipate just in case the data is like this below which means the position is no longer valid:

```
0297144600-4799      0297485500-5599      0297485600-5699
```

As you can see, I guess the first approach will the split by 1 blank space (" ") but due to number of space is unknown (varies) how do I take this approach then? Is there any method to find the space in between and shrink into 1 blank space (" ").

BTW ... it needs to be done in TSQL (Ms SQL 2005) unfortunately cause it's for SSIS :(

I am open with your idea/suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: How many possible number groupings will there be in a single line?   Are you interested in only retrieving 0297485500-5599, or any given value in the line?

Comment: The simplest I can think of would be to use a regex replace function to convert one or more spaces into one before further operation.  Doable, but requires a CLR function...

Comment: No I need to get 0297144600-4799 , 0297485500-5599 and  0297485600-5699 depending on that line. In term of possibility of number groups, it's unknown but from what the observation is that the total chars is never get 100 chars

Comment: Depending on how many spaces you anticipate will be between a given number, and don't want to use a CLR, you could do a whole bunch of replace(replace(replace(),'____'),'__'),'_'), but that's incredibly hacky (the underscores are spaces, the editor doesn't seem to like extra spaces in the comments).

Comment: Is the sequence (i.e. which set of numbers occurs first on the line) relevant?  Are the numbers always going to follow the pattern 1234567890-1234?  If so you could do some pattern matching and replace strings...

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: That's the issue is ... I don't know the number space in between. It varies.

Comment: @JNK: That pattern is always be different :(

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Thanks for that I am looking at your approach - http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/27/SQL-2005-Regular-Expression-Replace.aspx

Comment: I need to fix my site, but I do have a [CLR regex assembly that includes such functionality](http://www.mssqlclr.com/?page_id=27).  Sadly, the private documenatation pages aren't working the way I want, but I do include the VS project source at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're processing one line at a time, you can also try this:

```
DECLARE @InputString nvarchar(max)
SET @InputString = '0297144600-4799      0297485500-5599      0297485600-5699'
BEGIN
WHILE CHARINDEX('  ',@InputString) > 0  -- Checking for double spaces
  SET @InputString =
    REPLACE(@InputString,'  ',' ') -- Replace 2 spaces with 1 space
END
PRINT @InputString
```

(taken directly from [SQLUSA](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/removemultiplespaces/), fnRemoveMultipleSpaces[1](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/removemultiplespaces/))

Answer (score 2):

I have updated my answer a bit, now that I know the number pattern will not always match.  This code assumes the sequences will begin and end with a number and be separated by any number of spaces.

```
DECLARE @input nvarchar -- max in parens
DECLARE @pattern nvarchar -- max in parens
DECLARE @answer nvarchar -- max in parens
DECLARE @pos int
SET @input = '      0297144623423400-4799      5615618131201561561     0297485600-5699         '

-- Make sure our search string has whitespace at the end for our pattern to match
SET @input = @input + ' '

-- Find anything that starts and ends with a number
WHILE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%[0-9] %', @input) > 0
BEGIN
  -- Trim off the leading whitespace
  SET @input = LTRIM(@input)
  -- Find the end of the sequence by finding a space
  SET @pos = PATINDEX('% %', @input)
  -- Get the result out now that we know where it is
  SET @answer = SUBSTRING(@input, 0, @pos)
  SELECT [Result] = @answer
  -- Remove the result off the front of the string so we can continue parsing
  SET @input = SUBSTRING(@input, LEN(@answer) + 1, 8096)
END
```

Comment: PATINDEX? I will explore this.

Comment: The number could be anything such as  0297144600-4799 then  0297144600-0297144699. How can I handle that?